# Filter out duplicate rows based on a subset of columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have some data that looks like this:

```
ID,DateTime,Category,SubCategory
X01,2014-02-13T12:36:14,Clothes,Tshirts
X01,2014-02-13T12:37:16,Clothes,Tshirts
X01,2014-02-13T12:38:33,Shoes,Running
X02,2014-02-13T12:39:23,Shoes,Running
X02,2014-02-13T12:40:42,Books,Fiction
X02,2014-02-13T12:41:04,Books,Fiction
```

what I would like to do is to only keep one instance of each datapoint in time like this (I don't care which instance in time):

```
ID,DateTime,Category,SubCategory
X01,2014-02-13T12:36:14,Clothes,Tshirts
X02,2014-02-13T12:39:23,Shoes,Running
X02,2014-02-13T12:40:42,Books,Fiction
```

Unfortunately, according to the [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-ALLandDISTINCTClauses),  Hive's `DISTINCT` expression works on entire tables so doing something like this is not an option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ID, SubCategory),
       DateTime,
       Category
FROM sometable
```

How do I go about getting the second table above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach for this kind of thing in SQL is a group by:

```
select ID, category, subcategory, min(datetime) datetime
from sometable
group by ID, category, subcategory
```